# Unable to get Process CPU in Azure application insight

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I installed application azure insight in my .net mvc application(On VPS server) by following this 
[configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net)
But I am having issue with some counters like process CPU, Total CPU% etc.

While monitoring application in Live stream I can see request rate, request duration and request failure but committed memory and CPU% are empty

Same with processor time & process CPU in metrics explorer
[image: metric explorer]

please suggest if I done wrong while configuration.

Comment: Are you using .net core application? For .net core apps perf-counters are not supported.

Comment: Application is based on .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Ok then there are some issues with the performance counter collection module. The application insights SDK would report these errors. Can you search in your Traces for any messages starting with "AI:" . Also can you verify that the application has access to read performance counters? (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969639/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-the-performance-monitor-perfmon-e)

Answer (score 3):

we had a sort a like issue, the problem was that the user from the application pool did not have access to PerfMon

so the first solution was this on our dev servers: add everyone to the "Performance Monitor Services" on our dev server, and the the CPU and committed memory became visible in AI

[image]

i know giving everyone is not that correct, but we will look into it further, a better approach is to use the IIS_APPPool user

We ended up doing this during deploy step in our ymal

```
 - powershell: |
      try {
          Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Performance Monitor Users" -Member "IIS AppPool\${{ parameters.WebsiteName }}" -ErrorAction Stop
      } catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberExistsException] {
          Write-Warning "$member already in $group"
      }
    displayName: "‍♂️ Add IIS User to Performance Monitor Users"
```

Comment: This worked for me. However instead of adding Everyone, I added the user that has been  specified in the relevant App Pool and then reset iis. Immediately CPU, Requests etc started appearing.